Resized disk and immediately filled up
I'm on a VM, and I was low on space so I resized the disk to 100GB. I ran sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv to make use of the extra space, and now it shows my "104GB Block Device" as 99% full immediately. Did I do something wrong here, and is there any way to fix this? I can't seem to reverse this since it is all full again.
I am extremely new to Linux, so if possible, a dumbed-down answer would be ideal since there's still a lot I don't get. Thanks!

Where is this shown? Did you grow the filesystem as well?

This is shown in "Disks". Turns out I didn't grow the filesystem – all is good now. Is there any way I can shrink it? I think I gave the VM much more space than I needed to...

"Is there any way I can shrink it?" - yes, but if you've already grown the filesystem inside the container not easily

Give the full list of pertinent commands that you ran to add clarity to your question.
